Strange celery behaviour -- tasks don't seem to appear in redis however are sometimes run
[Updated after more research]
I'm running Celery attached to a Flask server in a custom container (daemonised using supervisord -- see below for config), with Redis as the backend. The container is running in Azure Web Apps for Containers and the Redis instance I'm using is hosted in Azure Cache for Redis
The app seems to start ok, and if I make a single web request which calls a task, it seems to work properly. The weirdness begins when I try to call several tasks in (reasonably -- multiple tasks per 10s let's say) quick succession -- the first task seems to run OK, however no further tasks run (unless I wait a while before calling again), nor do they appear to be queued (nothing appears in the queue and nothing further happens once the first task is done). I'm wondering whether that's because if the queue is empty/the worker isn't busy tasks just get passed straight across, though this doesn't answer why subsequent tasks aren't queued (unless there's some weirdness where Celery can read but not write to Redis)
I've tried to have a look in Redis at the queues themselves; by default there isn't a 'celery' queue, and one doesn't seem to be created when I schedule more jobs. Celery does appear to connect correctly to Redis though:
  -------------- celery@[app_name]__9a8a_eec99cfd v5.4.0 (opalescent)
 --- ***** ----- 
 -- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.153.1-1.cm2-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2024-06-10 15:50:53
 - *** --- * --- 
 - ** ---------- [config]
 - ** ---------- .> app:         web.app:0x70b55460fb10
 - ** ---------- .> transport:   rediss://:**@[host]:6380/0
 - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
 - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
 -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
 --- ***** ----- 
 
 -------------- [queues]                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
 
 [tasks]
   . module.task.name0
   . module.task.name1
   . module.task.name2
 
[2024-06-10 15:50:53,524: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to rediss://:**@[host]:6380/0

I've attached below other relevant components of my setup: how I'm instantiating my app and its config and the supervisord config file
My question is then: what could be causing the tasks to not be queued/run? The web server is definitely receiving the requests as I can see this in the logs, however it seems like once the worker is processing a task, any subsequent tasks get ignored, not even being queued.
One current theory about what's going wrong is it's something to do with the networking setup between the Azure Redis cache and my app, as when I ssh into my container and try to run Celery commands they fail with 'connection refused', however I'm not 100% as my app appears to be able to connect to Redis fine (my Flask app has an endpoint which writes to and reads from Redis and this also seems to work fine). I've also checked and the Redis instance is far below any memory limits, and never has CPU utilisation higher than 10%. Another is that it's something server-side which is meaning the tasks get dropped by Celery. An extra layer of weirdness is that I have seen it sometimes work (ie sometimes stuff does get queued in Celery) -- any help greatly appreciated!
from celery import Celery, Task
from flask import Flask

from utils.env_var import get_redis_connection_string

def init_celery(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config['CELERY'])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions['celery'] = celery_app

    return celery_app

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        CELERY={
            'broker_url': get_redis_connection_string(),  # does what you expect
            'task_acks_late': True,
            'worker_prefetch_multiplier': 1,
            'task_reject_on_worker_lost': True,
            'broker_connection_retry_on_startup': True,
        }
    )
    init_celery(app)


[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:celery]
command=celery -A web.make_celery.celery_app worker -c 1 -l info
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:gunicorn]
command=gunicorn -w 4 --bind=0.0.0.0:50505 --timeout 600 web.app:create_app()
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

